# Get the number of outliers by group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the number of outliers by group from a Pandas data frame.

My data looks like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':list('aaaabbbb'),
                   'val':[1,3,3,2,5,6,6,2],
                   'id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'mydate':['01/01/2011 01:00:00',
                             '01/01/2011 01:02:00',
                             '01/01/2011 01:05:00',
                             '01/01/2011 01:06:00',
                             '01/01/2011 03:00:00',
                             '01/01/2011 04:00:00',
                             '01/01/2011 05:00:00',
                             '01/01/2011 10:00:00']})
df
```

To get the number of outliers, I'm using the following function that gets the IQR.

```
def get_IQR():
    q1 = df["val"].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df["val"].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = (df["val"] > q1) & (df["val"] < q3)
    return val.loc[iqr]

df[["group","val"]].agg([get_IQR])
```

This doesn't work and produced the following results

```
ValueError: no results
```

Does anyone have a better strategy for finding the number of outliers per group, such that...

```
group   num_outliers
a        ...
b        ...
c        ...
```

Comment: Are you checking for outliers using all data or using data within each `group`?

Comment: in my example, I guess that I didn't group by group. But I did want it within each group...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use aggregate functions, you need to define it differently. Pandas will pass a vector to the function and function needs to output a single value. So:

```
def get_num_outliers (column):
 q1 = np.percentile(column, 25)
 q3 = np.percentile(column, 75)
 return sum((column<q1) | (column>q3))
```

Then call it like this:

```
 df.groupby('group').agg([get_num_outliers])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want outliers to be identified using `group`-specific quantiles, here's my crappy solution:

1.Calculate quantiles q1 and q3:

```
qs = df.groupby("group")["val"].quantile([0.25,0.75])
qs = qs.unstack().reset_index()
qs.columns = ["group", "q1", "q3"]
qs
  group    q1   q3
0     a  1.75  3.0
1     b  4.25  6.0
```

2.Merge it together with df:

```
df_m = pd.merge(df, qs, on="group", how="left")
df_m
 group  id               mydate  val    q1   q3
0     a   1  01/01/2011 01:00:00    1  1.75  3.0
1     a   1  01/01/2011 01:02:00    3  1.75  3.0
2     a   2  01/01/2011 01:05:00    3  1.75  3.0
3     a   2  01/01/2011 01:06:00    2  1.75  3.0
4     b   2  01/01/2011 03:00:00    5  4.25  6.0
5     b   3  01/01/2011 04:00:00    6  4.25  6.0
6     b   3  01/01/2011 05:00:00    6  4.25  6.0
7     b   3  01/01/2011 10:00:00    2  4.25  6.0
```

3.Get outliers:

```
df_m["Outlier"] = ~df_m["val"].between(df_m["q1"], df_m["q3"])
df_m
  group  id               mydate  val    q1   q3  Outlier
0     a   1  01/01/2011 01:00:00    1  1.75  3.0     True
1     a   1  01/01/2011 01:02:00    3  1.75  3.0    False
2     a   2  01/01/2011 01:05:00    3  1.75  3.0    False
3     a   2  01/01/2011 01:06:00    2  1.75  3.0    False
4     b   2  01/01/2011 03:00:00    5  4.25  6.0    False
5     b   3  01/01/2011 04:00:00    6  4.25  6.0    False
6     b   3  01/01/2011 05:00:00    6  4.25  6.0    False
7     b   3  01/01/2011 10:00:00    2  4.25  6.0     True
```

4.Get count:

```
df_m.groupby("group")["Outlier"].sum().astype(int)
group
a    1
b    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
q1 = df['val'].quantile(0.25)
q3 = df['val'].quantile(0.75)

df['Outlier'] = ~df['val'].between(q1, q3)

df.groupby('group')['Outlier'].sum().astype(int).reset_index()

#   group  Outlier
# 0     a        1
# 1     b        2
```

**Explanation**

- We define an `Outlier` column as a Boolean based on whether `val` is within the interquartile range.
- We then groupby `group` and sum the `Outlier` series. This is possible because `bool` is a subclass of `int`, i.e. `True == 1` and `False == 0`.
- Convert to `int` as result should only be whole numbers (`float` is default).

Comment: should it be count() instead of sum()?

Comment: @MikhailVenkov, I *think* it should be sum, since we only want number of outliers, not count of items.

Comment: @MikhailVenkov @jpp `count()` could be used if the `groupby` statement grouped by both `'group'` and '`Outlier'`.  I think that would obviate the need for `astype(int)` as well.

Comment: @PaSTE, fair point. Please do post the alternative as a separate answer, I think both ways are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way (based off of [jpp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48994249/5075720)):

```
q1 = df['val'].quantile(0.25)
q3 = df['val'].quantile(0.75)

df['Outlier'] = ~df['val'].between(q1, q3)

df.groupby(['group', 'Outlier'])['id'].count()

# group  Outlier
# a      False      3
#        True       1
# b      False      2
#        True       2
# Name: id, dtype: int64
```

**Explanation**:

- Define an `'Outlier'` column as a Boolean based on whether or not `'val'` is within the interquartile range.  Save this as a column in the DataFrame.
- Group by both the `'group'` and `'Outlier'` columns and [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) the occurances of some non-null field (in this case, I picked `'id'`, but you could pick any of the columns in your example, or just call `count` on the result of the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) without any column selection.)

The advantage of using this two-column `groupby` statement is that you get all of the group/Outlier combinations for free if you want to inspect them later.  To get the result in the format you are asking for specifically, subset by `'Outlier'` before grouping:

```
df.loc[df['Outlier']].groupby('group')['id'].count().reset_index().rename(columns={'id': 'num_outliers'})

#   group   num_outliers
# 0 a       1
# 1 b       2
```