# Clean Data Outliers with Pandas or Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning, outliers

I have a dataset with the following structure:

| timestamp | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | type A | 12345 |
| 2022-01-01 | type B | 12345 |
| 2022-01-01 | type C | 12345 |
| 2022-02-01 | type A | 12345 |
| 2022-02-01 | type B | 12345 |
| 2022-02-01 | type C | 12345 |

I now want to detect outliers and replace them with the mean of the belonging type. I can calculate the mean of the data and replace all the outliers in the dataset, but the problem is that it will calculate the mean of all the data and not the mean for each "type". Also, when replacing, it should check each type seperately if the current value is x-times the belonging mean and if yes, replace it. Currently it will not differentiate between different types.

What would be a solution in python for that problem? Is maybe an iteration possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks really similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994157/get-the-number-of-outliers-by-group-in-pandas (2nd answer)

Comment: How do you define "outliers"? 1.5x interquartile range from the mean?